# Python- Remove all words that contain other words in a list

Tags: python, string, list, loops

I have a list populated with words from a dictionary.  I want to find a way to remove all words, only considering root words that form at the **beginning** of the target word.

For example, the word "rodeo" would be removed from the list because it contains the English-valid word "rode."  "Typewriter" would be removed because it contains the English-valid word "type."  However, the word "snicker" is still valid even if it contains the word "nick" because "nick" is in the middle and not at the beginning of the word.

I was thinking something like this:

```
 for line in wordlist:
        if line.find(...) --
```

but I want that "if" statement to then run through every single word in the list checking to see if its found and, if so, remove itself from the list so that only root words remain.  Do I have to create a copy of wordlist to traverse?

Comment: Are there two lists? One from the dictionary and one containing your "root" words?

Comment: You suggest a doubly-nested pair of loops, one to consider each target word, and another to call the `.startswith()` method for each target word against every word in the valid list.  This would be quite slow.  Python for loops are not the fastest, and in any event Python provides some useful data structures with fast lookup.  In problems like this, you should consider "What data structures in Python would help here?"  A dictionary is possible but a set is ideal here.  It will be easier and faster to just try the various substrings of the target word in a fast set lookup, as I suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that you only have one list from which you want to remove any elements that have prefixes in that same list.

```
#Important assumption here... wordlist is sorted

base=wordlist[0]                      #consider the first word in the list
for word in wordlist:                 #loop through the entire list checking if
    if not word.startswith(base):     # the word we're considering starts with the base
        print base                    #If not... we have a new base, print the current
        base=word                     #  one and move to this new one
    #else word starts with base
        #don't output word, and go on to the next item in the list
print base                            #finish by printing the last base
```

EDIT: Added some comments to make the logic more obvious

Comment: You need to move the 'print base' to after the first line. Right now, this prints the last word twice, and the first not at all. Also, replacing print with yield gives you generator for the final list.

Comment: can you explain how this works?  I really don't get how this is supposed to remove from the wordlist all words that contain other words.

Comment: @Paul Hankin: While replacing print with yield will indeed give you a generator for the list, you're wrong about moving the print statements. Try a trivial testcase.

Answer (score 6):

So you have two lists: the list of words you want to check and possibly remove, and a list of valid words.  If you like, you can use the same list for both purposes, but I'll assume you have two lists.

For speed, you should turn your list of valid words into a set.  Then you can very quickly check to see if any particular word is in that set.  Then, take each word, and check whether all its prefixes exist in the valid words list or not.  Since "a" and "I" are valid words in English, will you remove all valid words starting with 'a', or will you have a rule that sets a minimum length for the prefix?

I am using the file /usr/share/dict/words from my Ubuntu install.  This file has all sorts of odd things in it; for example, it seems to contain every letter by itself as a word.  Thus "k" is in there, "q", "z", etc.  None of these are words as far as I know, but they are probably in there for some technical reason.  Anyway, I decided to simply exclude anything shorter than three letters from my valid words list.

Here is what I came up with:

```
# build valid list from /usr/dict/share/words
wfile = "/usr/dict/share/words"
valid = set(line.strip() for line in open(wfile) if len(line) >= 3)

lst = ["ark", "booze", "kite", "live", "rodeo"]

def subwords(word):
    for i in range(len(word) - 1, 0, -1):
        w = word[:i]
        yield w

newlst = []
for word in lst:
    # uncomment these for debugging to make sure it works
    # print "subwords", [w for w in subwords(word)]
    # print "valid subwords", [w for w in subwords(word) if w in valid]
    if not any(w in valid for w in subwords(word)):
        newlst.append(word)

print(newlst)
```

If you are a fan of one-liners, you could do away with the for list and use a list comprehension:

```
newlst = [word for word in lst if not any(w in valid for w in subwords(word))]
```

I think that's more terse than it should be, and I like being able to put in the print statements to debug.

Hmm, come to think of it, it's not too terse if you just add another function:

```
def keep(word):
    return not any(w in valid for w in subwords(word))

newlst = [word for word in lst if keep(word)]
```

Python can be easy to read and understand if you make functions like this, and give them good names.

Comment: This method is much less efficient than it has to be. (If I've got it right, `O(n²)` instead of `O(n)`)

Comment: Even if it is inefficient-- it's easy to understand.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I interpreted the question as "Remove (all words that contain other words) in a list", not as "Remove all words that contain (other words in [the same] list)".  If we only care about other words from within the list, this solution is overkill.  If you actually can provide an O(n) algorithm to solve the same problem I was solving, I predict it will involve a tree structure such as a trie.  I believe we should say this is an O(m*n) solution, where m is the average number of letters per word and n is the number of words.  It is definitely not O(n²) where n is the number of words in the list.

Comment: I agree that you are solving a slightly different problem. Am I right in thinking that `w in valid` takes O(n) time (`valid` is traversed)? Does that make this O(n*m) where `n` is `len(lst)` and `m` is `len(valid)`?

Comment: If `valid` were a `list`, then `w in valid` would take O(n) time.  But `valid` is a `set`, so `w in valid` takes O(1) time.  Actually for the fastest possible speed it should really be a `frozenset`; we don't need to change the set, ever, and I believe `frozenset` is slightly faster than `set` in return for not being modifiable.  A `dict` is also O(1) lookup.  (These all use hashing and I guess hashing run time might vary depending on how full the hash buckets are...)  http://pyref.infogami.com/frozenset

Comment: Thanks steveha, I had thoughts along those lines when I went to bed.

Answer (score 1):

I find jkerian's asnwer to be the best (assuming only one list) and I would like to explain why.

Here is my version of the code (as a function):

```
wordlist = ["a","arc","arcane","apple","car","carpenter","cat","zebra"];

def root_words(wordlist):
    result = []
    base = wordlist[0]
    for word in wordlist:
        if not word.startswith(base):
            result.append(base)
            base=word
    result.append(base)
    return result;

print root_words(wordlist);
```

As long as the word list is sorted (you could do this in the function if you wanted to), this will get the result in a single parse. This is because when you sort the list, all words made up of another word in the list, will be directly after that root word. e.g. anything that falls between "arc" and "arcane" in your particular list, will also be eliminated because of the root word "arc".

Comment: This algorithm will be very slow, if the list of valid words is at all large.  If you really want to do something like this, you should build some sort of tree structure to hold the valid words list; a "trie" would be ideal.  Then for each word you want to lookup, you would walk the trie instead of iterating over a possibly very long list of words.  /usr/share/dict/words on my Ubuntu computer is over 98 thousand lines, and for "cat" you really only care about the lines that start with 'c'.  You waste your time with 'a' and 'b' words and anything 'd' or after; that's why a tree is better.

Comment: @steveha: In some ways, a trie is a nifty solution to this problem, since you can trim it as you load it, and you never have a word terminating on a non-leaf. This would probably be the way to go if you needed to access the list repeatedly after loading and setting it up. On the other hand, it's a ridiculous amount of code-overhead for a simple task, the above version takes less than a tenth of a second on that words file on my ancient laptop.

Comment: I was solving a slightly different problem from the one Parseltongue actually wanted solved.  This answer is very similar to the accepted answer so it looks to me like you did a better job of understanding the actual requirements.  I agree that for finding words prefixed by other words only from within the same list, this is a better solution than mine.

Comment: @steveha I haven't read much on tries, but given that you start with a list of words, I would imagine it would be impossible to build a trie more efficiently than this function runs.

Comment: I withdraw my complaint that this will be slow, too.  I didn't understand your code when I wrote that.  Sorry.  Yes, I agree that the Python to build a trie would be slower than this; you would only try something like the trie if you wanted to handle a really large separate list of valid words.  As long as you are only finding valid words from within the same list, this is simply better.  By the way, I haven't tried it, but I think you could do a slick trie in Python using `dict`s nested inside other `dict`s.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built-in  `lambda` function for this. I think it'll make your life a lot easier

```
words = ['rode', 'nick'] # this is the list of all the words that you have.
                         # I'm using 'rode' and 'nick' as they're in your example
listOfWordsToTry = ['rodeo', 'snicker']
def validate(w):
    for word in words:
        if w.startswith(word):
            return False
    return True

wordsThatDontStartWithValidEnglishWords = \
    filter(lambda x : validate(x), listOfWordsToTry)
```

This should work for your purposes, unless I misunderstand your question.

Hope this helps

Comment: This has the bad running time O(N^2) [try it on a full dictionary, and see how long it takes]. Also the lambda is redundant: `lambda x: validate(x)` is equivalent to `validate`.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Would you be up to posting a better version of this code? I'd love to see how my code can be made better. BTW, I'm not challenging you or anything, I sincerely want to know what your ideas are

Comment: See the approved answer by jkerian, it's seriously faster than this.

Comment: The approved answer only works with one list.  To see a faster alternative to your code that works with two lists, please see my answer.  In your code, `validate()` uses a `for` loop to check every word in your word list; this is really slow.  In my code, the list of valid words is turned into a `set` so that checks can be O(1), and then various prefixes from the target word are checked.  Since a 5-letter word has 4 prefixes to try, this should be a lot faster than trying every word in the `words` list with `.startswith()`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an answer that assumes two lists, the list to be pruned and the list of valid words.  In the discussion around my answer, I commented that maybe a trie solution would be good.

What the heck, I went ahead and wrote it.

You can read about a trie here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

For my Python solution, I basically used dictionaries.  A key is a sequence of symbols, and each symbol goes into a dict, with another Trie instance as the data.  A second dictionary stores "terminal" symbols, which mark the end of a "word" in the Trie.  For this example, the "words" are actually words, but in principle the words could be any sequence of hashable Python objects.

The Wikipedia example shows a trie where the keys are letters, but can be more than a single letter; they can be a sequence of multiple letters.  For simplicity, my code uses only a single symbol at a time as a key.

If you add both the word "cat" and the word "catch" to the trie, then there will be nodes for 'c', 'a', and 't' (and also the second 'c' in "catch").  At the node level for 'a', the dictionary of "terminals" will have 't' in it (thus completing the coding for "cat"), and likewise at the deeper node level of the second 'c' the dictionary of terminals will have 'h' in it (completing "catch").  So, adding "catch" after "cat" just means one additional node and one more entry in the terminals dictionary.  The trie structure makes a very efficient way to store and index a really large list of words.

```
def _pad(n):
    return " " * n

class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = {}  # dict mapping symbols to sub-tries
        self.w = {}  # dict listing terminal symbols at this level

    def add(self, word):
        if 0 == len(word):
            return
        cur = self
        for ch in word[:-1]: # add all symbols but terminal
            if ch not in cur.t:
                cur.t[ch] = Trie()
            cur = cur.t[ch]
        ch = word[-1]
        cur.w[ch] = True  # add terminal

    def prefix_match(self, word):
        if 0 == len(word):
            return False
        cur = self
        for ch in word[:-1]: # check all symbols but last one
            # If you check the last one, you are not checking a prefix,
            # you are checking whether the whole word is in the trie.
            if ch in cur.w:
                return True
            if ch not in cur.t:
                return False
            cur = cur.t[ch]  # walk down the trie to next level
        return False

    def debug_str(self, nest, s=None):
        "print trie in a convenient nested format"
        lst = []
        s_term = "".join(ch for ch in self.w)
        if 0 == nest:
            lst.append(object.__str__(self))
            lst.append("--top--: " + s_term)
        else:
            tup = (_pad(nest), s, s_term)
            lst.append("%s%s: %s" % tup)
        for ch, d in self.t.items():
            lst.append(d.debug_str(nest+1, ch))
        return "\n".join(lst)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.debug_str(0)



t = Trie()


# Build valid list from /usr/dict/share/words, which has every letter of
# the alphabet as words!  Only take 2-letter words and longer.

wfile = "/usr/share/dict/words"
for line in open(wfile):
    word = line.strip()
    if len(word) >= 2:
        t.add(word)

# add valid 1-letter English words
t.add("a")
t.add("I")



lst = ["ark", "booze", "kite", "live", "rodeo"]
# "ark" starts with "a"
# "booze" starts with "boo"
# "kite" starts with "kit"
# "live" is good: "l", "li", "liv" are not words
# "rodeo" starts with "rode"

newlst = [w for w in lst if not t.prefix_match(w)]

print(newlst)  # prints: ['live']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to provide an exact solution, but I think there are two key functions in Python that will help you greatly here.

The first, jkerian mentioned: string.startswith() http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

The second: filter() http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter

With filter, you could write a conditional function that will check to see if a word is the base of another word and return true if so.

For each word in the list, you would need to iterate over all of the other words and evaluate the conditional using filter, which could return the proper subset of root words.

Comment: I tried to play around with filter on this, you need to use a filtering function that stores some outside state (the 'base', from my example above), which turns out to be rather odd-looking.

Comment: I admit I did not try and write the code. I would think it would be possible to use another word from the list as a base for comparison. I think steveha nailed it though.

Answer (score 0):

I only had one list - and I wanted to remove any word from it that was a prefix of another.

Here is a solution that should run in O(n log N) time and O(M) space, where M is the size of the returned list. The runtime is dominated by the sorting.

```
l = sorted(your_list)
removed_prefixes = [l[g] for g in range(0, len(l)-1) if not l[g+1].startswith(l[g])] + l[-1:]
```

- If the list is sorted then the item at index N is a prefix if it begins the item at index N+1.
- At the end it appends the last item of the original sorted list, since by definition it is not a prefix.
  Handling it last also allows us to iterate over an arbitrary number of indexes w/o going out of range.

If you have the banned list hardcoded in another list:

```
 banned = tuple(banned_prefixes]
 removed_prefixes = [ i for i in your_list if not i.startswith(banned)]
```

This relies on the fact that startswith accepts a tuple. It probably runs in something close to N * M where N  is elements in list and M is elements in `banned`. Python could conceivably be doing some smart things to make it a bit quicker.  If you are like OP and want to disregard case,  you will need `.lower()` calls in places.